# Is there an OS X equivalent of FreeBSD's make_dev() function?

Tags: macos, port, freebsd, ioctl, mknod

I'm trying to port some code from FreeBSD to OS X.  The code is fairly low-level and it creates a number of special device files using [`make_dev()`](http://man.freetechsecrets.com/make_dev.9.html) and controls functionality using functions like [`ioctl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl).

Ideally I'd like to keep my code as close to the original as possible so I can more easily merge upstream changes in the future: my question is, is there a way to create such device files on OS X?   According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) the idiom is supported on the platform.   Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you writing a kernel extension, or porting a userland app? What's wrong with mknod(2) for your usage?

Comment: The source code I'm trying to port is a kernel extension: if I can work in userland though I would rather.  It seems that via IOKit I can get at the actual device data I need, so if I can create special device files in userland that function the same as devices created in /dev by a kernel extension that would be fine.  Is that the way it works?

Comment: did you find/get the DVB source code?

Comment: @tommieb75: no I didn't but I found some FreeBSD code that I can understand and am going to have a go porting.  I'd rather avoid writing a kernel extension but it seems that I'll have to if I want to keep my code close to the source I'm using.

Comment: Ok...have fun with the porting and best of luck with it ;) I'll keep an eye on future postings from you as I would be interested in how are you getting on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've answered my own question: it seems the function to do this is `devfs_make_node()`.  I can't find a man page but it is shown in some example code [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOSerialFamily/IOSerialFamily-11/IOSerialFamily.kmodproj/IOSerialBSDClient.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mknod.2.html), `mknod` does work on OS X.  What problems are you having with it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a hasty edit: I'm not sure mknod does the same thing as make_dev...